# How to execute a PowerShell script only before a web deploy Publish task in VS 2012?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, publish, msdeploy, post-build-event

Currently I have a post-build event configured in my web project using Visual Studio 2012 like this:

[image]

This basically calls a [PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199409/114029) to add a copyright notice to every .cs file.

What I'd like to do is to execute this powershell script ***only before*** Publishing the web app to the remote server. Doing so I won't experience a delay every time I need to debug the project. Do you know of any way of accomplishing this?

---

According to [Sayed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12920499/114029), I customized a specific publish profile and added this:

```
<PipelineDependsOn>
  CustomBeforePublish;
  $(PipelineDependsOn);
</PipelineDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomBeforePublish">
<Message Text="******* CustomBeforePublish *******" Importance="high" />
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -file &quot;$(ProjectDir)\Copyright.ps1&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Sorry, but did you add a new PropertyGroup in addition to the one already existing in the pubxml?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends on how you define before but below is one technique.

When you create a publish profile with VS2012 it will create you a .pubxml file in the Properties\PublishProfiles folder (*My Project\PublishProfiles for VB*). These are MSBuild files and you can edit them to customize the publish process. In your case you can inject a target into the publish process, before the publish actually occurs. You can do that by extending the PipelineDependsOn property as below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PipelineDependsOn>
    CustomBeforePublish;
    $(PipelineDependsOn);
  </PipelineDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CustomBeforePublish">
  <Message Text="********************************** CustomBeforePublish ***********************************" Importance="high"/>
</Target>
```

FYI regarding the customization of .wpp.targets, that was the only technique which we had for VS2010. My recommendation here is as follows; customize the .pubxml file for most cases and to only create a .wpp.targets file if you want to customize every publish of the given project.

Comment: What if I want to execute something *after* (not before) publishing?

Comment: Hi Sayed, Im trying this in vs2015 and I'm getting an error when i select publish. Error: "The attribute Name in element <Target> is unrecognized". Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

`Sayed`'s answer nails the problem. However, I thought about providing a fully working answer (testing in Visual Studio 2017):

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PipelineDependsOn>
       PreBuildScript;
       $(PipelineDependsOn);
    </PipelineDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PreBuildScript">
     <Message Text="Executing prebuild script" Importance="high"/>
     <Exec Command="powershell.exe -file &quot;$(ProjectDir)\InnerFolder\script.ps1&quot;" />
   </Target>
```

**Note:** This will execute for both Preview and actual Publish action, so one can find out pre-publish errors before the actual Publish.

Answer (score 4):

Declare the following `ProjectName.wpp.targets` file in the root of your web application:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BeforeAddContentPathToSourceManifest>
      $(BeforeAddContentPathToSourceManifest);
      AddCopyright;
    </BeforeAddContentPathToSourceManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AddCopyright">
    <!-- I recommend passing in $(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath) to your script
         as the base path to search to avoid having to perform a VCS rollback 
         (files are copied there before the deployment)
     -->
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -file &quot;$(SolutionDir)Copyright.ps1&quot; &quot;$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)&quot;" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Richard. As you can see in Sayed's answer there's a way of customizing a specific publish profile and that was a better fit in my case.

Comment: See my answer below about using .wpp.targets with VS2012

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi - Thanks for the heads up. You should consider getting the docs updated as they're documented as being equals (as far as relevance is concerned).

Comment: Can you give me a link to what you are referring to?

Comment: In the doc the first sentence for the .wpp.targets section is "Settings that you configure in the .wpp.targets file apply to all publish profiles." Do you think we need to change it?