# How to all #nullable disable to all files in solution

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I want to migrate my codebase to nullable references. One of [migration strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies) consists of adding `#nullable disable` prefix to all files. How I can do it automatically?

Comment: There is a related question about adding a copyright header to all files. The solutions/scripts found there might solve your problem as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199409/87698

Comment: Note that `file_header_template` won't work -- it doesn't support the `#` character (which gets parsed as a comment), so `#nullable` is right out

Comment: The biggest challenge is to not alter encoding on any file

Comment: Go to Replace in Files, check "Use regular expressions", set the "Find" box to `^(?<![.\n])` (which will match the start of a file), and the Replace box to `#nullable disable` (and maybe a trailing newline?). Make sure to use the File types to filter to .cs files. Test carefully first!

Comment: @canton7 thanks, that's great! Can you post this as answer so you get all the fame? :)
You need to replace with `#nullable disable\n`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to:

1. Go to "Replace in Files"
2. Check "Use regular expressions"
3. Set the "Find" box to `^(?<![\n])`
4. Set the "Replace" box to `#nullable disable\n`
5. Set the "File types" to at least contain `*.cs`
6. Test carefully! I like to do a "Find All" first to make sure the matches are what I want, and use a backup/version control.

[image: Screenshot of the above]

`^(?<![\n])` is a regex which matches the start of a line (`^`) which isn't preceeded by a newline (`(?<![\n])`). In other words, the start of the first line of a file.

Comment: In case project does not compile after this you may want to use `git clean -fxd` to remove all ignored files and build from scratch.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you might want to consider replacing with `#nullable disable\r\n` instead to avoid the "inconsistent line endings" message box each time you open a code file afterwards.

Comment: We were changing from the opt-in to the opt-out nullable model, so I wanted to only add this to every file that didn't already have the `#nullable enable` directive. This regex seemed to do the trick `^(?<!.|[\n])(?!#nullable enable)`. The regex in this answer also seems to incorrectly include the literal `.` character inside the character set `[.\n]`. Although I'm fairly certain just looking for newline would be enough anyway, `(?<![\n])`