# Can you turn off the nullable reference type feature(s)?

Tags: c#-8.0

I just started my first project with c#8 and immediately I'm hit with warnings everywhere on my properties. After some research, it looks like I'm now supposed to explicitly add a ? to any properties that can be null.

Two questions:

1. If I port code from previous versions to this version, does this actually affect runtime in anyway whatsoever, or do I just have to ignore a bunch of warnings?
2. Is there a simple switch to revert to the old behavior so it won't show these warnings? I understand that there are ways I could update my code in a million places to ignore the warnings... I don't want to do that. It's a waste of time and I'd rather live with them if they don't actually affect anything at runtime. But if there is something I can do in a single place to get rid of them that would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to all #nullable disable to all files in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119049/how-to-all-nullable-disable-to-all-files-in-solution)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable null validation in ASP.Net 6 project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71350179/11683)

Comment: @GSerg Yes, the 2nd one seems to do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. The nullability analysis feature only reports warnings, it doesn't affect runtime in any way.
2. Yes you can suppress those diagnostics, `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in the project file or `#nullable disable` at the top of your source file will do it.

Comment: Where exactly does it need to be put in the .csproj file? I tried adding it before the last `</Project>` line, ,but it won't load the file then

Comment: It needs to be in a <PropertyGroup> tag

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I look this up long ago...

Comment: I owe you a beer...

Comment: Point 1 is actually not correct. It does change how libraries interpret your code. For example System.Text.Json or EntityFrameworkCore. So there is a difference between suppressing the warnings and turning the feature off.

Answer (score 0):

`#nullable disable` actually change the runtime sometimes. for example on deserialization input of Api on string field, and if set enable you get bad request error.
you can also set `#pragma warning disable CS8618` on code or set it
in .editorconfig file and add to YourSolution.sln.
[image]