# How do I initialize a multi-dimensional array in C# when the size is not known at the point of initialization?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

I need a two-dimensional array of objects as a field in a class "World".
When the class "World" is initialized, I do not yet know the size of the two-dimensional array, since this is set in a GUI after initialization.
How do I do this?
I have searched for examples where the array is initialized as empty, but how do I then resize the array after initialization?
I am probably approaching this situation in the wrong way, but since I need the field in the world object and don't know the size of the array at initialization, I'm stuck.
Any advice would be appreciated.

I tried initializing an empty array, but can't find how to resize a multi-dimensional array.
I also thought about putting the array in another class, but in such a case that class would need to be initialized as well, so that won't solve this problem.
A List is probably not the solution since I'm working with a two-dimensional grid, and I assume a two-dimensional array would be most appropriate for that.
Below is the relevant example. Without initializing the squareGrid array in the constructor, I get "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS8618  Non-nullable field 'squareGrid' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable."

```
    public class World
{
    Square[,] squareGrid;

    public World(ref DimensionsAndStuff dimstuffIn)
    {
        // some other stuff going on
    }
}
```

Comment: Array.Resize(ref YourArray, SizeYouWant);

Comment: Define your array as `myLovelyClass[,] array` and then create the appropriate size when knowing the dimension `array = new myLovelyClass[myXDimension, myYDimension]`. A single Dimension would also easily work it is just a bit of different simple math moving between indexes.

Comment: I would at least consider creating your own 2D array type that wraps a 1D array. Some things, like serializing data, tend to be easier for 1D arrays, since multi dimensional arrays tend to not be as well supported by tools and libraries.

Comment: Your question reads as if you do not actually need to resize the Array, just initialize it to the correct size at a later point in time? In that case, @Ralf s suggestion will work just fine. No need to actually initialize the array during startup

Answer (score 0):

You can just instantiate the array after you know its dimensions by using a method that takes the dimensions as parameters e.g.

```
public class World
{
    private int[,] _coordinates;
    
    public void SetupCoordinatesGrid(int xSize, int ySize)
    {
        _coordinates = new int[xSize, ySize];
    }
}
```

Then you would setup the multi-dimensional array after you know the dimensions.

```
var w = new World();
w.SetupCoordinatesGrid(xValue, yValue);// where xValue & yValue are existing variables set via user input
```

###### Update

If you have "nullable reference types" enabled then explicitly mark `_coordinates` as nullable i.e.

```
public class World
{
    private int[,]? _coordinates;
    
    public void SetupCoordinatesGrid(int xSize, int ySize)
    {
        _coordinates = new int[xSize, ySize];
    }
}
```

Comment: That does  not seem to work. If I don't initialize the array in the constructor of the class "World", where the array is declared, I get "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS8618 Non-nullable field 'squareGrid' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable. "

Comment: I see. You must have nullable reference types enabled. You can either disable it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370168/19214431) or explicitly mark `_coordinates` as nullable.

Comment: Yes! This seems to  solve it! Thank you!