# How to tell VS that member is not null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullable

I have a class that is like

```cs
    class Operation
    {
        private int? opA = null;
        private int? opB = null;
        private Func<int>? opFunc = null;

        public void SetOperandA(int value)
            => opA = value;
        public void SetOperandB(int value)
            => opB = value;

        public void SetAdd()
            => SetOperator(() => (int)opA + (int)opB);
        public void SetSubtract()
            => SetOperator(() => (int)opA - (int)opB);

        public void SetOperator(Func<int> op)
        {
            if (opA is null || opB is null)
                throw new Exception("Both operands must be set first!");
            opFunc = op;
        }

        public int Evaluate()
        {
            if (opFunc is null)
                throw new Exception("Operator must be set first!");
            return opFunc();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that in the `SetAdd()` function, VS complains about the line `SetOperator(() => (int)opA + (int)opB);` saying that `opA` and `opB` may be `null`, even though they should never both be `null` by how `SetOperator()` works.

I'm trying to tell VS that it's as if I'm doing

```cs
        public void SetMultiply()
        {
            if (opA is null || opB is null)
                throw new Exception("Both operands must be set first!");

            opFunc = () => (int)opA * (int)opB;
        }
```

where VS is able to deduce that at the line `opFunc = () => (int)opA * (int)opB;`, both `opA` and `opB` aren't `null` and there are no potential issues.

I've tried adding

```cs
        [MemberNotNull(nameof(opA))]
        [MemberNotNull(nameof(opB))]
        private void SetOperator(Func<int> op) { /* ... */ }
```

but this doesn't affect what I'm after.

Comment: See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367986/can-you-turn-off-the-nullable-reference-type-features

Comment: @RTF I do not wish to disable null checking

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [null-forgiving operator (`!`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving):

```cs
public void SetAdd()
        => SetOperator(() => (int)opA! + (int)opB!);
public void SetSubtract()
        => SetOperator(() => (int)opA! - (int)opB!);
```

Which is basically the same as "shut up, I know better".

Or use the pragma - `#nullable`:

```cs
#nullable disable
    public void SetAdd()
        => SetOperator(() => (int)opA + (int)opB);
    public void SetSubtract()
        => SetOperator(() => (int)opA - (int)opB);
#nullable restore
```

Comment: Sadly C++ lacks this mercy.  The compiler neither forgives nor forgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null-forgiving operator (!), which tells the compiler that you're absolutely certain that the value won't be null. You can do this by adding ! after the nullable variable.

Try changing the line:

setoperator(() => (int)opa + (int)opb);

to:

setoperator(() => (int)opa! + (int)opb!);

This should resolve the issue in Visual Studio and allow you to compile the code.